# "Could not obtain an instance of KeyTabKeytab is corrupted"

Tags: java, synchronization

We are getting an issue "Could not obtain an instance of KeyTabKeytab is corrupted" with JDK 1.6 or JDK 1.5.

The reason for this issue in JDK 1.6 or 1.5 was observed as that the method `sun.security.krb5.internal.ktab.KeyTab.getInstance(java.lang.String s)` which creates the instance for the keytab file was not able to load the keytab file properly, due to the reason that this method is not synchronized.

This issue was happening in our environment under 100 users load test consistently, I looked into the SUN code and found that synchronization for the method "`sun.security.krb5.internal.ktab.KeyTab.getInstance(java.lang.String s)`" is missing, it looks to be fixed in JDK 1.7 by making the `KeyTab.getInstance(java.lang.String s)` .
So to get around the above problem I have added sychronization in my code as shown below as I'm not sure how Sun libraries load the keyTab for each login context.

```
LoginContext loginContext = new LoginContext(contextName);
synchronized(KerberosUtility.class)
{
loginContext.login();
}
```

Since the method "`sun.security.krb5.internal.ktab.KeyTab.getInstance(java.lang.String s)`" is synchronized in JDK 1.7, I'm planning to remove the synchronization block in the above mentioned code snippet which is surrounded by `loginContext.login()`.

Do you see any issues here if I remove the synchronization?

Had you come across this issue earlier and solutions for the same?